# Java code, passing arguments to method

Tags: java, argument-passing

I'm not sure what I did wrong here, 
this is my code

```
package methods;

public class example {
    public static int sum(int x, int y){ 
        return x+y; 
    }
    public static void printSomething() {
        int a = 1; 
        int b = 2; 
        System.out.println("The sum of "+ x + " and "+ y +" is "+sum(a,b)); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello"); 
        printSomething();
    }
}
```

I want to print the sum of x and y is 3

Comment: What does your code actually do? You appear to be using variables, `x`, and `y`, inside of the `printSomething()` method that are not within the scope of that method, and this should prevent your code from compiling -- is this what is wrong? Solution: use `a` and `b` there. `System.out.println("The sum of "+ a + " and "+ b +" is "+sum(a,b));`

Comment: `System.out.println("The sum of x and y is "+sum(a,b)); `

Comment: Ok, thank you for the solution. just out of curiosity, and I'm a noob and new to this site why did i get -1 for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("The sum of "+ a + " and "+ b +" is "+sum(a,b));
```

The parameter names `x` and `y` are *local* to the method definition, in the current scope they're called `a` and `b`.

Alternatively, and for consistency's sake you could simply rename `a` and `b` to `x` and `y` in the `printSomething()` method. The result will be exactly the same, but now the variables will have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
package methods;

public class example {
    public static int sum(int x, int y){ 
        return x+y; 
    }
    public static void printSomething() {
        int a = 1; 
        int b = 2; 
        System.out.println("The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + sum(a,b)); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello"); 
        printSomething();
    }
}
```

You can't access local variables (such as x, y of sum method) inside other method this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want to achieve, but check if this helps:

```
package methods;

public class example {
    public static int sum(int x, int y){ 
        return x+y; 
    }
    public static void printSomething() {
        int a = 1; 
        int b = 2; 
        System.out.println("The sum of "+ a + " and "+ b +" is "+sum(a,b)); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello"); 
        printSomething();
    }
}
```